# SignTypedData in ethers version 6.9.0

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ethers.js

Does anyone know how to perform signTypedData in ethers version  6.9.0 . I am tryin to do this but it reverts with `this function doesnt exist` . I am trying to create a signer usin g JavaScript Provider by passing the testnet url.